# Manual actions in Selenium

Tags: java, python, selenium, webdriver

started the test in Selenium in addition in my browser I manually clicked and/or entered the data in the fields.

Is it possible to save the actions that I made manually - actions logs?
I want to know what the user's actions during manual test.

Comment: How can _Manual actions_ be part of _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB when selenium starts a test, than open broswer and then you can manually for example click a link

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Selenium with third-party framework like Robotframework.

It will be easier to observe actions with those behavior driven test framework.

And they will also help you to capture screenshot while error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this code for screenshot :

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
 File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
 // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
 FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: I think the goal is to be able to capture actions as events.

Answer (score 0):

Sławomir, why don't You start record all actions from beginning, after launch webbrowser. For FF55+ there is an addon Katalon Recorder. You can record all steps and than export all actions to Java, Pyton code. Than just copy code from exporter, and You can use it in your webdriver tests.

Comment: No, it isn't solution. Below i put example.

Answer (score 0):

Below example

---

Simple example

During the test Selenium opens a page example.com. Next Selenium click on link to example.com/login. On the login page Selenium enters username and password *-- it is correct test*

---

Example with manual actions

During the test Selenium opens a page example.com. **Now manually I click on link example.com/about (but on About page isn't link to example.com/login** Next Selenium try to click on link to example.com/login, but can't because link to example.com/login doesn't exist. *-- test failed*

---

Test failed because I make manual action, so I want to log all manually actions